# Javascript - Constructor's properties & Prototype

Tags: javascript, function, object, constructor, prototype

I'm trying to understand one thing about constructors. Namely I don't understand how function object's properties, aka constructor's properties can't be accessed using Foo.prototype.property, example:

```
//let's create new function object with predefined properties
function Foo() {
    this.name = "Mike"; 
    this.returnName = function() {
                       return 'This persons name is ' + this.name + '.';
                      };
};

//now let's create new object using constructor and prototypal inheritance
var mike = new Foo();

mike.returnName(); //returns "This persons name is Mike."
```

I understand that mike inherits properties from Foo's prototype. So these properties must be present inside of the prototype. new object points toward the prototype with internal prototype link using __ **proto** __. I get that.
Thing that I can't get around is how this doesn't work:

```
Foo.prototype.returnName();
```

Constructor has .prototype link with prototype property and vice versa prototype has .constructor link with the Foo.

I know that calling the Foo(); 
function first then calling for window.returnName(); would return the    sentence, since this context is set to window.

Is this because when I call the method using prototype it assigns it to the window? Is there any way I could access/call this constructor's property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying returnName on the prototype of Foo. If you would do it like this:

```
function Foo(){
    this.name = "Mike"; 
}

Foo.prototype.returnName = function(){
   return 'This persons name is ' + this.name + '.';
};

var mike = new Foo();

mike.returnName();
```

Things would be different.

Comment: Ok I think I'm starting to get it. Just 1 more clarification. Where does the mike variable from my example get the properties from? If they aren't present in prototype of Foo rather within Foo function object itself, does this mean that when I call new Foo();, new object gets properties from the constructor and if I ever add property to the prototype it will also gain these? It surely must do right? If it does and I create 100x of instances of that function object I'd have 100 instances with these 2 properties each. Right? Meaning that adding properties to prototype in that case is better?

Comment: You are absolutely right. That's the whole idea of Prototypal Inheritance ;)

Answer (score 0):

The function `returnName` is not assigned to the prototype of `Foo`. Instead it's assigned to every instance of `Foo`, just like the `name` is `"Mike"`.

Whenever you call `new Foo()` a new context is created, this is the `this` context of that instance.

If you call `Foo()` directly (without `new`) `this` is the global object (`window`).